# How to set background color on a specific date?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, fullcalendar

I used fullcalender npm for displaying the calendar.
I want to set a background color on the specific selected date.

I checked this issue on github [link](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/237).

But dayRender was replaced in the v5 version.

I want to achieve this output like to set the background color on a specific date.

[image]

Can anyone know if Is there any other function available? which works like dayRender.

Or can anyone guide on how to achieve this output with fullcalender.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS and DOM structure has been refactored in v5.

dayRender was replaced by **day-cell render hooks**.

Please read these 2 articles:

1. Go to section: Date Rendering -> dayRender
   https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/upgrading-from-v4
2. How to use day-cell render hooks:
   https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/day-cell-render-hooks

Comment: Thank you @Ferris I am also looking for the same issue can you please share a good example with day-cell render hooks if available.

Comment: @Ferris Thank you so much for your help. Can you know How to add dayCellClassNames(with Day-Cell Render Hooks) in specific dates inside the td tag using a full calendar in angular? Much appreciate for your help.